# Updating per user stats in SignalR hub

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, asp.net-identity, signalr-hub, signalr-backplane

I'm working on a simple game using SignalR 2 and MVC 5.  I need to track number of "deaths" and "kills" for each user.  These stats need to be read/write from multiple game instances (user can have multiple concurrent sessions) across multiple servers.

**Is adding fields to `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser` a reasonable solution?**  I'm planning on using the built-in authentication system because I like how easy it is to support Facebook and other OAuth providers.

**How should I update these stats in an optimized manor that reduces multi-user/threads/server issues and is highly scalable?**  The stats themselves are simple, and probably only update once every few seconds per user, but I'd like a design that can support millions of users across multiple servers.

For example, I know I could add this code inside an MVC controller to update the stats:

```
    var um = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var user = um.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    user.Deaths++;
    um.Update(user);
```

However, that doesn't seem very safe/transactional.  If another process/connection/server is updating that user at the same time, bad things are likely.

In a pure SQL design I'd probably have a stored procedure that runs in a SQL transaction to get current counter, and increment it.  Not sure how to translate that to a good SignalR design that takes advantage of all that the various API layers have to offer (OWIN, MVC, ASP.NET, etc).  Ideally something I can easily add Redis to down the road, if direct SQL access becomes an issue.

Comment: I agree, that in a multi-threaded context having the death/kill counter updated in the database could lead to unsafe transactions. I would try pushing items to a common queue, with a single threaded processing class that de-queues them and performs the appropriate action.

Comment: Also - thank you for preemptively supporting multi-instance gamers. We appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas.  I'm hoping something as common as I think this is has a simple existing solution, but if not, the queue idea sounds good and I'll probably just implement Redis at the same time, if I have to go to that trouble anyway.

Comment: If the class updating SQL is guaranteed to be a single-instance, you could use `lock`.